# Create string from regular expression PHP

Tags: php, regex, url

I'm trying to create a string from a regular expression. I noticed that in Kohana framework's routing system you can set a route using something similar to a regular expression. Then you can create an url matching a route you've set. I'm trying to do something similar, but I can't find a clean way to do it. I've for example got the following regular expression:

```
/^(?<application>\w+)\/(?<controller>\w+)\/(?<method>\w+)\/(?<parameters>\w+)\/?$/
```

Now I want to be able to say that "application" equals "a", "controller" equals "b", "method" equals "c" and "parameters" equals "d". Then I should get a string that replaces the parts with the values specified. I can't find a good way to do this though. I've basically thought of two ways: 1) replace the corresponding values in the regular expression with the specified values, or 2) create a custom "regex syntax" that you can easily be used to create string and convert it to a "proper" regular expression when needed. Kohana uses the latter, but both ways sound quite bad to me. How would you do this?

**Edit:** I'll try to clarify it a bit. I for example pass the following string to the regular expression shown above using `preg_match()`: "myApplication/myController/myMethod/myParameters". This returns an array that has a couple of items, including 4 items with indexes "application", "controller", "method" and "parameters" with the corresponding values. Now I have to create the string "myApplication/myController/myMethod/myParameters" with the regular expression's pattern while I only have that array with the 4 items. How can I do this using PHP?

Comment: This is not clear.  Can you please give an example of an input string and the corresponding output string?

Comment: I'm very familiar with php and regular expressions, however I have no clue what you are asking for. Your question made zero sense to me, I suggest you edit your question from scratch. But who knows, maybe somebody else understands.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, Gerry: I understand it's probably hard to understand, I was having trouble explaining it myself... I added some text and hope it is clearer now.

Comment: @Frog: Your question is only slightly clearer now.  Is the general rule "xyz" -> "myXyz"?

Comment: Thanks for the response @Oli Charlesworth! No, that's not really what I mean. I have to create a string that corresponds to the pattern in the regular expression, with the values from an array filled in the named groups. I basically have to do the reverse operation: I've got the regex and the values, now I have to fill in the values in the regex, so I get a string that would when passed to `preg_match()` with the regex return the same values. Did I explain myself?

Comment: @Gerry: please look below at Alan's answer, I believe he understands what I mean and maybe that can help you understand it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be pretty straightforward given that `preg_match` has support for **named capturing groups** (which your regular expression is, of course, using; [more here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html)).

An example [from PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
<?php

$str = 'foobar: 2008';

preg_match('/(?P<name>\w+): (?P<digit>\d+)/', $str, $matches);

/* This also works in PHP 5.2.2 (PCRE 7.0) and later, however 
 * the above form is recommended for backwards compatibility */
// preg_match('/(?<name>\w+): (?<digit>\d+)/', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);

?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foobar: 2008
    [name] => foobar
    [1] => foobar
    [digit] => 2008
    [2] => 2008
)
```

So in your case, you can use your `$matches` array, e.g. `$matches['application']`.

---

**Edit:** Okay, I did not fully understand the question.

An obvious problem with using regular expressions to *generate* strings is that a regular expression can match infinite strings. For example, `/cat\s+rat/` matches all of:

```
cat rat
cat  rat
cat   rat
```

etc.

But in your example, nothing is undefined.

So your inclination to define a "safe" or singly-generatable language that is a subset of regular expressions is a good one, given a narrow use case. Then you could replace occurrences of `/\(\?P?<(\w+)>\)/` with the value of the capturing group in there.

But since PHP doesn’t really let you just use the value of the capturing group to access a variable during replacement in one step, you will likely have to do this in multiple steps… e.g. matching all occurrances of the above group, extracting the named groups, and then finally doing (in a loop over `$matches` as `$match`) a simple string substitution from `'(?P<' . $match . '>)'` and `'(?<' . $match . '>)'` to the value of `$$match` (though in a safer way than that).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understand that and that's exactly what I'm doing right now. What I'm trying to do though is reverse this operation: I know what (in your example) "name" is and what "digit" is, now I want to create a string that corresponds to the regex pattern with the values I know. So for example, I know that "name" equals "test" and "digit" equals "2000", my function should then create a string "test: 2000".

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Alan H.! That's exactly what I mean, and your example is really helpful. So you think that using a subset of regular expressions is the best way? Doesn't it drastically slow down the page?

Comment: Well, how many times would you do something like this per pageview? A small number of times should be relatively insignificant.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I'm sure your answer somehow wasn't showing up here yesterday when I checked..? Anyways, it probably won't happen more than 3 times on each page view. I'm currently creating my own subset and it's actually going quite well. :)