# Reverse regular expression, create string from regex

Tags: regex

I am working on a multilingual site and have chosen to use custom URLs per language as well, so for example:

```
/en/cities/paris/
/nl/steden/paris/
```

Both point to the Index method of the Cities controller.

On every page there's an option to switch language and it will look in my routes to match controller, view and language.

So if I'm on the Dutch page, it will find the proper url for the English version, which will be 'cities' instead of 'steden'.

All worked fine, up until I started using more complex regular expressions.

I have these regular expressions that will match my desired URLs:

```
#^en/cities/([^/]+?)/$#
#^nl/steden/([^/]+?)/$#
```

In my code I have access to the variable that's being matched, 'paris' in this example. Would it be possible to 'reverse' this regular expression and have it print 'en/cities/paris/'

If not.. how would I go about having links to different versions of the same page, considering the URLs are different.. preferably have it as programmable as possible.

In a somewhat similar question, someone answered (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7070734/616398) that the essense of regex is to match an infinite number of results.. so it might not be possible.

It's quite easy to go from a string/URL to a set of matched criteria to use in a MVC, but the other way around.. not so much, unfortunately.

Comment: Regular languages can be used to construct statements, but that is certainly not what you are looking for. They construct rooms of statements ('languages'), not single statements, since there is nothing telling the engine which statement to pick. Instead I suggest you implement a dictionary of url patterns and create a function to query that dictionary, for example by city name.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have settled with using {city}  in my route and then include some metadata about what {city} should get replaced with to get a proper regex, then later I can change {city} again, this time with the proper data. It works for my complex regexes and the simple ones that are just text-only. So I'm happy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's possible ! For this case I've coded the following solution:

```
$regex = '#^en/cities/([^/]+?)/$#';
$replace = array('paris');

$result = preg_replace_callback('#^\^|\([^)]*\)|\$$#', function($m)use($replace){
    static $index = 0;
    if($m[0] === '^' || $m[0] === '$'){return '';}
    if(isset($replace[$index])){
        return $replace[$index++];
    }
    return $m[0];
}, substr($regex, 1, -1));
echo $result; // en/cities/paris/
```

**[Online demo](http://viper-7.com/R5nS7g)**

I've made it "flexible" so you can add more values to it !

```
$regex = '#^en/cities/([^/]+?)/region/([^/]+?)$#'; // <<< changed
$replace = array('paris', 'nord'); // <<< changed

$result = preg_replace_callback('#^\^|\([^)]*\)|\$$#', function($m)use($replace){
    static $index = 0;
    if($m[0] === '^' || $m[0] === '$'){return '';}
    if(isset($replace[$index])){
        return $replace[$index++];
    }
    return $m[0];
}, substr($regex, 1, -1));
echo $result; // en/cities/paris/region/nord
```

**[Online demo](http://viper-7.com/Af0cS8)**

---

**Explanation:**

```
$regex = '#^en/cities/([^/]+?)/region/([^/]+?)$#'; // Regex to "reverse"
$replace = array('paris', 'nord'); // Values to "inject"

/*  Regex explanation:
   #   Start delimiter
       ^\^         Match "^" at the begin (we want to get ride of this)
       |           Or
       \([^)]*\)   Match "(", anything zero or more times until ")" is found, ")"
       |           Or
       \$$         Match "$" at the end (we want to get ride of this)
   #   End delimiter
*/

$result = preg_replace_callback('#^\^|\([^)]*\)|\$$#', function($m)use($replace){
    static $index = 0; // Set index 0, note that this variable is only accessible in this (anonymous) function
    if($m[0] === '^' || $m[0] === '$'){return '';} // Get ride of ^/$ at the begin and the end
    if(isset($replace[$index])){ // Always check if it exists, for example if there were not enough values in $replace, this will prevent an error ...
        return $replace[$index++]; // Return the injected value, at the same time increment $index by 1
    }
    return $m[0]; // In case there isn't enough values, this will return ([^/]+?) in this case, you may want to remove it to not include it in the output
}, substr($regex, 1, -1)); // substr($regex, 1, -1) => Get ride of the delimiters
echo $result; // output o_o
```

> <sub>**Note**: This works only on **PHP 5.3+**</sub>

Comment: This answer just gave me a mild aneurysm ;p